# javascript Cannot read property 'createDocumentFragment' of undefined

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm trying to load from my database using ajax and the `this` method don't seem to work.

here is my source code:

```
$(".cancel-btn").click(function() {
  var cancelArea = $('.cancel');

  let userID = $('.person-title').data('user-id');

  $.get(`users/${userID}`).done((docs) => {
    $(docs).each((i) => {
      $(cancelArea).append(
        `<div class='cancel-box text-center' data-sessionID="${docs[i]._id}" onclick='cancelSession()'>
            <div class='cancel-trainer'>${docs[i].trainedByName}</div>
            <div class='cancel-date'>${docs[i].date}</div>
            <div class='cancel-hour'>${docs[i].startTime}</div>
          </div>`
      );
    });
  });
});
```

and here is the function I'm trying to run

```
function cancelSession() {
  console.log($(this).data('sessionID'));
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead

```
<div class='cancel-box text-center' data-sessionID="${docs[i]._id}" onclick='cancelSession(this)'>
```

JS:

```
function cancelSession(element) {
  console.log($(element).data('sessionid'));
}
```

Comment: Try changing to lowercase "sessionid" in the data()-call. i created a sample fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/18k37wLn/2/